# Styling SP Enterprise 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have a question about styling and images on my site(s) - We are going to have ~25 site collections created for our organization. We want all of the styling and images to come from our root site so we don't have to update each site collection every time. However, when I add the styling to the root and then connect to the site collection via a content editor, I'm getting the following message: "Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property. For more assistance, contact your site administrator."

Can someone give a little guidance on what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day!

Content editors cannot link to files from outside your site collection. So you will run into the error you described in your message. Content editors can only link to files inside of its own site collection.

What you CAN do is edit your master page, and link to CSS and JavaScript that is stored in the site assets of another root site collection. Please be careful though to ensure that users have access to that other site collection, otherwise the CSS and JavaScript will fail to load.

You can edit the master page either through SharePoint designer, or by going to site settings, master pages and page layouts, and editing the HTML version of the file there.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. If you find the solution to be the correct one, may I ask you to mark the response as the accepted answer. Thanks.